# Changed DB Owner

Tags: sql-server, database, owner

I accidentally changed the DB owner to SA.  Is there logging that would show what the previous DB owner was?

Thanks.

Comment: which DBMS you are using (MySQL,Oracle,...??)? How you notice, that you have changed the DB owner?

Answer (score 1):

The database owner is stored in the master database (`sysdatabases` or `sys.databases` table; please always mention your version of SQL Server). So you could restore a backup of the master database to a new instance of SQL Server, query the old owner and set it back on your production instance.

It would also be interesting to know why the database owner is important to you. In most environments I've seen, all databases are owned by sa and users who need database owner permissions are added to the db_owner role explicitly. This is a better way to handle permissions, because only one login can be the database owner, but multiple users can have database owner permissions. Therefore, using the db_owner role is more flexible.